# Android: не появляется виджет

Tags: android, java

Написал для приложения виджет.

Загрузил на смартфон: работает, всё ок.

У друзей не работал.

Решил переустановить свою программу, удалив все настройки и т.п.

Виджет пропал со списка виджетов.

В чём дело?
Делал по мануалу,на эмуляторе работает.

Comment: Приложение установлено на карте памяти или в основной памяти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандарт Андроида подразумевает хранение приложений в основной памяти устройства, возможно, вы пытаетесь установить его на карте памяти.